# react native: how to place icon (or view) on image by tap

Tags: react-native

I want when I touch the image, at that position will show the icon at the touch position, and maybe when zooming, the icon can be enlarged accordingly. In short, I want the icon to stick at that position, but when the image is zoomed or moved, the icon also zooms or moves.
Also is there any way when we take a picture from the phone to get the exact size of it

```
i tried by position, but i wonder if there is any way that can be attached to it, i want it to always be in that position no matter what the picture is. Help me
```

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution to this?